# GCloud Laravel notification custom template in resource view vendor dir

Tags: laravel, email, templates, notifications, gcloud

I'm creating a microservice for gcloud with laravel. everything works properly, but my problem is related to the custom template of email notification feature. In particular It seems not to be considered the customization in resource/view/vendor/mail folder. In local everything works fine, but once deployed the template is ignored and the message is sent with default laravel notification template. I suppose it is related to the configuration in app.yaml file, in the handler area, am I correct? In that case I would not know how to enable the application to see properly that folder. thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found! serve static files configuring handlers in app.yaml:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files